# DNA micro satelite counter

Tags: python

I wrote a code to run over the letters in a variable `fragile_x_test`
and count the number of "CGG". as long as the while loop encounter "CGG" it will add it into the counter variable `repeat`, otherwise, it will break from the while loop and go for the "if" loop below.

After the `if` loop, I want the code to go back to the while loop and continue running over the letters. But I don't want it to go back to the `for` loop at the beginning because it will reset the `i`.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that? many thanks!

this is the code:

```
fragile_x_test = "CGGCGGCGGCGGCGGACTTCACGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGG"


for i in range(0,len(fragile_x_test)):
    repeat = 0
    tandem = 0 
    while fragile_x_test[i:i+3] == "CGG": 
        repeat += 1
        i = i+3
    if repeat >= 5:
        tandem +=1
        i = i+3
```

Comment: Could you tell us what the result should be for the string given?

Comment: eventualy, the "tandem" counter will be added to a value of a certain key in a certain dictionary. in this dictionary, there will be a set of keys represented by genes, in which their value will be the number of tandem repeats (hence, the "tandem" counter). this is just a short example of the code. in a wider aspect, i want this code to run on a set of values from a dictionary, and then add the "tandem" counter to values in the dictionary i was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

**1st method :**

With .split(), you can directly get the number of 'CGG' in your string.

```
len(fragile_x_test.split('CGG'))-1
```

It should also be easier to calculate the tandem variable with it.

**2nd method :**

If you don't need to work on the non 'CGG' part of the string, you can use .count()

```
fragile_x_test.count('CGG')
```

**3rd method :**

This method only counts 1 occurrence for each one or more "CGG" in a row and will add one to tandem variable each time there is more than 5 "CGG" in a row.

```
example="|CGGCGGCGGCGGCGG|ACTACT|CGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGG|"


count , repeat , tandem = 0 , 0 , 0
for element in example.split('CGG')[1:-1]:   
    if element == '':
        count+=1
        if count==4: tandem+=1
    else:
        count=0
        
    if count==1:
        repeat+=1

print("Number of CGG in a row : ",repeat)
print("Number of CGG tandems : ",tandem)
```

It will print repeat=2 and tandem=2.

Comment: hey, thanks for answering! 
in a certain string, i need to: 
1. count the number of CGG's in a row (next to each other) 
2. if that number is equal or above 5, i want to add them to a new variable "tandem"

what i am asking is - will the command that you wrote will counter the number of times a CGG is apearing 5 or more times in a row? 


for an example: 
"|CGGCGGCGGCGGCGG|ACTACT|CGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGG|"

will the command that you wrote will find that 2 CGG's repeats? 
*sorry for the bad english

Comment: In your example, my code will return 12 as it counts twelve occurences of "CGG". I understand better your question now. You can still use .split() and .count() to solve your problem. I am going to edit my message above.

Comment: hey alex, thank you for your time! 
i think i made it too messy and missunderstood. therefore, i made a new post with new detalis, you are welcome to check it out! 
and thanks once again :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63836847/counting-the-number-of-cgg-in-microsatelites