# Counting the number of CGG in microsatelites

Tags: python

I have this task to find a number of repeats of CGG in a sequence that stored as a value in a dictionary (named "dict" below as an example). The number of repeats in a row should be 5 or higher. For an example: `CGGCGGCGGCGGCGG` and above. Lets call this repeat: "tandem".
Once I find this kind of tandem, I will have to count how many "CGG"s there is for the particular tandem.
Here is a dictionary for that example.

```
dict={ind_1:"ACGGCGAGCGCGGGCGGCGGCGGTGACGGAGGCGCCCGTGCCAGGGGGCGTGCGGCAGCG**CGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGG**GCCTCGAGCGCCCGCAGCCCACCTCTCGGGGGCGGGCTCCCGGCGCTAGCAGGGCTGAAGAGAAGATGGAGGAGCTGGTGGTGGAAGTGCGGGGCTCCAATGGCGCTTTCTACAAGGTACTTGGCTCTAGGGCAGGCCCCATCTTCGCCCT", 
ind_10:"ACGGCGAGCGCGGGCGGCGGCGGTGACGGAGGCGCCCGTGCCAGGGGGCGTGCGGCAGCGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGAGCGCCCGCAGCCCACCTCTCGGGGGCGGGCTCCCGGCGCTAGCAGGGCTGAAGAGAAGATGGAGGAGCTGGTGGTGGAAGTGCGGGGCTCCAATGGCGCTTTCTACAAGGTACTTGGCTCTAGGGCAGGCCCCATCTTCGCCCT"}
```

For an example, in the value of the first key (ind_1), there is only 1 tandem (in Bold), because it consist of 1 repeated CGG that is 5 or higher. In this tandem, it should have 47 "CGG"s in that tandem.
Meaning, once I find a tandem that has 5 repeated CGGs in a row, I need to count the number of CGG's in that particular Tandem
I tried this code:

```
dict_results = {}
for key,value in dict.items():
   tandem = 0
if value.count("CGGCGGCGGCGGCGGCGG"): 
    tandem = value.count("CGG")
dict_results[key] = tandem
```

But for the first value (ind_1), it said I have 58 repeats.
It counted **all** of the CGG's in the sequence, and not the onces in that particular tandem (that there's 47 of them).

My goal is to have 47 repeats after the iteration is done.

I have also tried with a threshold:

```
fragile_x_test_results = {}
for key,value in fragile_x_test.items():
    tandem = 0
    if value.count("CGG") > 5: 
        tandem = value.count("CGG")
    fragile_x_test_results[key] = tandem
```

But still no luck. I got 58 instead of 47 repeats of CGG

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by testing the presence of n*"CGG" in the string with .index() and decreasing the value of n (int). For example, in a string of length 20, you test if 6*"CGG" is present : if yes, you remember it and you create the substring without this 6*"CGG" and then you try it with 5*"CGG" etc...

The function below works on this logic and is able to detect if you have more than one tandem of the same lenght in the string:

```
def tandem_search(pattern,string):
    st=string
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(dic['ind_1'])//3+1,5,-1):
        while True:
            try:
                j=st.index(i*pattern)
                result.append(i)
                st=st[:j]+st[j+i*3:]
            except:
                break
    return(result)
```

With it, I get the following results:

```
tandem_search("CGG",dic['ind_1']) = [47]
tandem_search("CGG",dic['ind_10']) = [70]
```